# SQL Server: Give a name to an IP address

Tags: c#, sql-server

I Setup a SQL Server on Computer A and now want to deploy a C# App on Computer B which will access Database from A. Every thing is OK, but the problem is, whenever the Modem is restarted, the IP Address changes, so I have to change the IP address in Connection string of C# App and have to recompile it.
I have to deploy it on a client's office where multiple computers will access the database from another computer.
The server name where SQL Server is installed can be accessed by the name which is KAMAL-ASHRAF but on client computers, I can't access the server by Its name and I have to use the IP to access it.
Is there any way I can access the Server by a name instead of IP Address on the Client computer?

Comment: Uhh... like `nslookup KAMAL-ASHRAF`?

Comment: DNS is your friend.

Comment: Don't hardcode configuration...

Comment: Please, can you tell in details how to resolve this problem?

Comment: This would be better asked on ServerFault, if it's not already asked. Search for a tutorial on how to create and use a dns-server. Windows Server has for example one included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "can not" access the server by Name...

make sure your server is having a proper DNS server configured. 
and ensure your server is updating his ip at the dos server during ip address changes.

If this is not possible due to "circumstancis" you should read about dynamic dns provider (like dyndns.org) -  if you are try to connect through the internet.

OR try to give the DB server a fixed IP Address in you network in case it is local connection.

Comment: I gave static IP Address to the DB Server.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting fixed IP (Static IP).